# Removendo row de valores NaN de um DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Eu juntei duas tabelas através do comando `pd.concat` e me deparei com o problema de haver vários valoes NaN.

Acontece que existem valores que estão faltando em um dos dataframes. Para facilitar meu estudo de Data Science eu quero remover todos as **row** com valores NaN.

Aceito outras sugestões.

Dados:

```
    Ano Country Name  Pobreza  Population
1     1960  Afghanistan      NaN   8996351.0
265   1961  Afghanistan      NaN   9166764.0
529   1962  Afghanistan      NaN   9345868.0
793   1963  Afghanistan      NaN   9533954.0
1057  1964  Afghanistan      NaN   9731361.0
1321  1965  Afghanistan      NaN   9938414.0
1585  1966  Afghanistan      NaN  10152331.0
1849  1967  Afghanistan      NaN  10372630.0
2113  1968  Afghanistan      NaN  10604346.0
2377  1969  Afghanistan      NaN  10854428.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dropna

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0], [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5]],
                       columns=list('ABCD'))

df
   A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
```

Drop colunas nas quais **todos** os elementos sejam `nan`:

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')    
    A    B  D
0  NaN  2.0  0
1  3.0  4.0  1
2  NaN  NaN  5
```

Drop colunas nas quais quaisquer elementos sejam `nan`:

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
   D
0  0
1  1
2  5
```

Drop linhas nas quais **todos** os elementos sejam `nan` (nesse caso, não temos nenhuma):

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
```

Manter somente linhas com pelo menos 2 valores que não sejam `nan`:

```
df.dropna(thresh=2)
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
```